# What is meant by "adjoint" map to loop space?

Tags: algebraic-topology, loop-spaces

I have continuous map $f:S^2\to X$. Then there is some kind of an "adjoint" map $\hat{f}:S^1\to\Omega X$. What is it?

Comment: Write $S^2\cong \Sigma S^1\cong S^1\wedge S^1$.

Comment: @Tyrone Hmm... I can guess that $\hat{f}$ takes $x\in S^1$ and maps it to the loop $f((x,y)):S^1\to X$, where $(x,y)\in S^1\wedge S^1$. Is this the correct definition?

Comment: Yes $\hat f(x):y\mapsto f(x\wedge y)$. Recall that $\Omega X= C_*(S^1,X)$ is the set of basepoint preserving map $S^1\rightarrow X$ in the compact-open topology. Since $S^1$ is locally compact, $\hat f$ is continuous if and only if $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @Tyrone What do you denote by $x\wedge y$?

Comment: $x\wedge y\in S^1\wedge S^1$ is the equivalence class of $(x,y)$ in $S^1\wedge S^1=S^1\times S^1/S^1\vee S^1$.

Comment: Oh, got it, thanks!

Comment: See "Eckmann–Hilton duality", https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_space